# How to store data securely in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a web application with a rest api in expressjs and the frontend in reactjs. I would like to have access to the user information on my react app as well as know if the user is logged in without api calls. How do big apps solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to have access to user information in my React app as well as know if the user is logged-in *without* api calls.

At one point or another, you will *need* to make calls to your API in order for **React** to retrieve the information it needs.

Now, whether or not you need to make that request just once or on every route change is entirely dependent on the functionality of your application.

Generally, the way "big apps" approach this is with the use of [sessions](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html). A session is a cookie stored on the front end that is attached to a user's logged-in state (`true` or `false`). *See [key-value pairs](https://javascript.info/object#:%7E:text=A%20property%20is%20a%20%E2%80%9Ckey,or%20add%2Fremove%20a%20file.)*.

So, whenever you need to fetch sensitive data or protect a certain page from invalidated users, you would send this cookie (key) along with the API request to validate on your back end.

A generic flow might look something like this:

1. The user logs in on the front end.
2. Their credentials are validated on the backend (via your API), and a session token is returned.
3. The session token is stored on the front end as a [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).
4. The user attempts to access or retrieve some sensitive information via the API.
5. The session token is sent in the request headers to be validated in the back end, where either:

   A) The appropriate information is returned from the API, or

   B) An error asking the user to revalidate.

Obviously, this is quite a simplified explanation of everything, so I would heavily suggest you take a poke around about sessions and the handling of user data.

Good luck!

Comment: how can i do if i want to access user information for example in profile page without having to call my API? knowing that informations must be secure and uneditable...

Comment: If it's a user's public profile, you would fetch their relevant *public* information with your API. If it's a private profile (such as in the settings), the same thing applies - just with the session token for validation.

Comment: @HenriDufresne Why are you so against using an API? If you look at *any* of the "big apps" that you talk about, you will notice *all* of them will use countless API calls throughout your experience.

Answer (score 1):

Like GROVER. said, you have to make at least one API call to fetch the data

About the cookie validation part, [JWT](https://jwt.io/introduction) could be handy, it contains 3 parts separated by dots (.):

1. Header (type of token and signing algorithm)
2. Payload (expiration, your data, issuer, ...)
3. Signature (encoded with secret string; for validation in the backend later)

You can set payload in the express.js and then in the frontend you can parse data, then you can only check JWT "offline" in the frontend (for example check only expiration time in the payload, or just parse data from the payload without any validation, but I would *not* highly recommend this to you because of security) or validate token with an API call to your backend (because your secret should be only in the backend)